# Is it possible to retrieve a value from a redirect in another class before performing the redirect?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am currently working with a controller, `OnboardingController.php`. This controller calls another method in a different class, let's call it `OnboardingService.php`, so for example:

OnboardingController

```
public function doThing()
{
    return $this->doAnotherThing();
}
```

OnboardingService

```
public function doAnotherThing()
{
    return redirect('/')->with(['propertyA' => 'valueA']);
}
```

Would I be able to access `propertyA` in `OnboardingController` before returning the redirect? And if so, how would I access that property?

e.g.

OnboardingController

```
public function doThing()
{
    $doAnotherThing = $this->doAnotherThing();
    Log::info($doAnotherThing->propertyA);

    return $doAnotherThing;
}
```

I am currently using Laravel 6.

Comment: `with()` is just saving to the session, so no reason you shouldn't be able to get its value using `session('propertyA');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `redirect(...)->with(...)` to flash propertyA, so propertyA should be accessible from the session

```
public function doThing()
{
    $doAnotherThing = $this->doAnotherThing();
    Log::info(session()->get('propertyA'));

    return $doAnotherThing;
}
```